# Select a maximum of a count where a column determines the type of grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

## Help

Among the clients which only use a single company, find the different passengers who have flown the most. Result set: passenger name, number of trips

[Details]https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBr7E.jpg [Check This]

I have this Query

```
SELECT P.name, COUNT(T.trip_no) AS journeys, C.name as namecompany
FROM
Passenger P, Trip T, Company C, Pass_in_trip PIT
WHERE
P.ID_psg = PIT.ID_psg AND PIT.trip_no = T.trip_no
AND T.ID_comp = C.ID_comp
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
Passenger, Trip, Company, Pass_in_trip
WHERE Pass_in_trip.ID_psg = P.ID_psg AND Pass_in_trip.trip_no = Trip.trip_no
AND Trip.ID_comp <> C.ID_comp)
GROUP BY P.name, C.name;
```

I have this Result set:

```
# name, journeys, namecompany
'Alan Rickman', '1', 'Don_avia'
'George Clooney', '1', 'Dale_avia'
'Harrison Ford', '3', 'British_AW'
'Michael Caine', '4', 'British_AW'
'Mullah Omar', '4', 'British_AW'
'Nikole Kidman', '3', 'Don_avia'
'Russell Crowe', '1', 'British_AW'
'Steve Martin', '2', 'British_AW'
```

I want to separate the results by One peer one Like

```
# name, journeys, namecompany
'Michael Caine', '4', 'British_AW'
'Nikole Kidman', '3', 'Don_avia'
'George Clooney', '1', 'Dale_avia'
```

Comment: Did You try MAX(COUNT(T.trip_no)) instead of COUNT(T.trip_no)?

Comment: @Gopal There may be a logical problem with simply doing that, namely that it would give the wrong value.

Comment: i trying that, but mysql says that i have a error un group statements D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this query you get max value by company name. Try This

```
SELECT subquery.name, MAX(subquery.journeys),subquery.namecompany FROM
(
    SELECT P.name, COUNT(T.trip_no) AS journeys, C.name as namecompany
    FROM Passenger P, Trip T, Company C, Pass_in_trip PIT
    WHERE P.ID_psg = PIT.ID_psg AND PIT.trip_no = T.trip_no
    AND T.ID_comp = C.ID_comp
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
       Passenger, Trip, Company, Pass_in_trip
       WHERE Pass_in_trip.ID_psg = P.ID_psg 
       AND Pass_in_trip.trip_no =    Trip.trip_no
       AND Trip.ID_comp <> C.ID_comp)
       GROUP BY P.name, C.name
)AS subquery GROUP BY subquery.namecompany;
```

Comment: what's the difference between both the queries as Tim answered the same

Comment: @CarlosPolo This query has a problem and will not even run on many RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the accepted answer is technically wrong, because it includes columns in the `SELECT` clause which are not specified as aggregates in the `GROUP BY`.  The following solution uses a two subquery approach.  The second subquery obtains the max number of journeys for each company, and the first subquery connects each company name with the passenger.

Also note that I rewrote the original query to use explicit joins, making it easier to read and maintain.

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.jouneys, t2.namecompany
FROM
(
    SELECT P.name, C.name AS namecompany, COUNT(T.trip_no) AS journeys
    FROM Passenger P INNER JOIN Pass_in_trip PIT
        ON P.ID_psg = PIT.ID_psg
    INNER JOIN Trip T
        ON T.trip_no = PIT.trip_no
    INNER JOIN Company C
        ON C.ID_comp = T.ID_comp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
        Passenger, Trip, Company, Pass_in_trip
        WHERE Pass_in_trip.ID_psg = P.ID_psg AND Pass_in_trip.trip_no = Trip.trip_no AND
        Trip.ID_comp <> C.ID_comp
    )
    GROUP BY P.name, C.name
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.namecompany, MAX(t.journeys) AS maxJourneys
    FROM
    (
        SELECT P.name, C.name AS namecompany, COUNT(T.trip_no) AS journeys
        FROM Passenger P INNER JOIN Pass_in_trip PIT
            ON P.ID_psg = PIT.ID_psg
        INNER JOIN Trip T
            ON T.trip_no = PIT.trip_no
        INNER JOIN Company C
            ON C.ID_comp = T.ID_comp
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM
            Passenger, Trip, Company, Pass_in_trip
            WHERE Pass_in_trip.ID_psg = P.ID_psg AND Pass_in_trip.trip_no = Trip.trip_no AND
            Trip.ID_comp <> C.ID_comp
        )
        GROUP BY P.name, C.name
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.namecompany
) t2
    ON t1.namecompany = t2.namecompany AND t1.journeys = t2.maxJourneys
```

Comment: i don't understand, can you explain more please? how can i wrap my current query ?

Comment: Just try running my query.  If it works, then we'll discuss your questions.

Comment: This is the solutio D: i pass about 1 hour trying to solve this query i really glad C:

Comment: Your first query is good :D the second is better but its more complicated to understand but you help me a lot :D